# Scrape Number of Ratings for Each Product from Amazon

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to Scrape product rating from amazon..I have a csv containing thousands of urls of different products from amazon...the program runs but it skips many urls and return "NA". Below is the code:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)
require(rvest)

file1 <- read.csv("amazon.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")


for(i in 1:nrow(file1)){

  amazonlink <- as.character(file1$links[i])
  amazonlink <- paste("http://www.amazon.in/dp/", amazonlink, sep = "")
  amazonhtml <- read_html(amazonlink)


  tryCatch({ file1[i, 2] <- amazonhtml %>% html_node("#averageCustomerReviewRating") %>% html_text() %>% as.character() },error=function(e){})

}
```

and the file amazon.csv contains 1 column containing following:

B0117H62QK
B0104ZR8E6
B010NE3U2M
B00MF2MV1W
B00O0R02V6
B00PLXFIF8
B00LEG3BCI
B00KKLFFFE
B00MUESLHI
B00Q2FTXAA
B00LGMG942
B00N1WCMXC
B00KQK94OW
B00LM5E2K6
B00O4WJ560
B00GRKTH1U
B00O8LV4DO
B00Q2FPPAW
B00H816B5W
B00LFHRXC0
B00MF2MRLG
B00NWDX3GU
B00QK14G4E
B00QIMF1SK
B00MO4XQLU
B00NLBBHW0
B00LGMDS14
B00NTWXV7A
B00O4WJICQ
B00LGMG27G
B00O4WKWBW
B00PW65G2E
B00OM4YRV8
B00P156MH4
B00PLX18RA
B00R4N3WKQ
B00QC6MAA4
B00QC6JN7C
B00R4N35DK
B00Q818HZA
B00R4N4Y3U
B00SWFDP3Y
B00RNZ0SX4
B00S7SO4Z4
B00R4N3DXC
B00SVE9S00
B00T9N0Y9G
B00SMRDETW
B00T9N1MCE

these are just 50, there are 1000's of these, so for more links u can duplicate the links and run the code.

Comment: What would you want as an output? What is the goal here...

Comment: @Jason: output would be rating of a product..for example: rating of http://www.amazon.in/dp/B0117H62QK , is 3.7 out of 5

Comment: Just a heads up to be sure your scraping doesn't contravene Amazon's [Conditions of Use](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=footer_cou?ie=UTF8&nodeId=508088)

Comment: You are violating Amazon's ToS & encouraging others to do so

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for all examples in your file, but this is a start at least and if you provide some more info, I can maybe piggyback on this for the rest.

```
library(rvest)
amazon_rating<-read_html('http://www.amazon.in/dp/B0117H62QK')

gsub('.*\\(| .*','',
amazon_rating %>%
  html_node('#merchant-info') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
)

"4.3"
```

Comment: the code you have shared is almost similiar to mine..the problem i am facing is when i run the code for many links then some links dont get run

Comment: Sure but how is anybody supposed to troubleshoot that unless they know the links and which ones don't run?

Comment: some links might run sometime but misses out other time..u can try yourself..just make a csv and run the code i have given